# why doesn't 'follow' button on Django work?

Tags: django

I have built user folloing functionality with Ajax, so a user can follow/unfollow another user. The problem is that when I click "follow" button nothing happens and the number of subscribers doesn't change.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[path('users/',user_list,name='user_list'),
path('users/follow/',user_follow, name='user_follow'),
path('users/<str:username>/',user_detail,name='user_detail'),
path('',PostList.as_view(), name='index'),
path('<str:username>/new/',News.as_view(), name='new'),
path('<str:username>/', user_posts, name='profile'),
path('<str:username>/<int:post_id>/', post_view, name='tak'),
path('<str:username>/<int:post_id>/add_comment/', comment_add, name='add_comment'),

path('<str:username>/<int:post_id>/edit/', Update.as_view(), name='edit'),
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def user_list(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    return render(request,'user_list.html',{'section': 'people','users': users})
@login_required
def user_detail(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,username=username,is_active=True)
    return render(request,'user_detail.html',{'section': 'people',
    'user': user})


@ajax_required
@require_POST
@login_required
def user_follow(request):
    user_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if user_id and action:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if action == 'follow':
                Contact.objects.get_or_create(user_from=request.user,user_to=user)
            else:
                Contact.objects.filter(user_from=request.user, user_to=user).delete()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'error'})
    return JsonResponse({'status':'error'})
```

user__detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% block title %}{{ user.get_full_name }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ user.get_full_name }}</h1>

  
</div>
{% with total_followers=user.followers.count %}
<span class="count">
<span class="total">{{ total_followers }}</span>
follower{{ total_followers|pluralize }}
</span>
<a href="#" data-id="{{ user.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow"class="follow button">
{% if request.user not in user.followers.all %}
Follow
{% else %}
Unfollow
{% endif %}
</a>
  
{% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
{% block domready %}
$('a.follow').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $.post('{% url "user_follow" %}',
 {
 id: $(this).data('id'),
 action: $(this).data('action')
 },
 function(data){
 if (data['status'] == 'ok') {
    var previous_action = $('a.follow').data('action');
 // toggle data-action
 $('a.follow').data('action',
    previous_action == 'follow' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow')
 $('a.follow').text(
    previous_action == 'follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');
 // update total followers
 var previous_followers = parseInt(
 $('span.count .total').text());
 $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'follow' ?
 previous_followers + 1 : previous_followers - 1);
}
 }
 );
 });
{% endblock %}
```

project/common/decorators.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.http.response import HttpResponseBadRequest
def ajax_required(f):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__=f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__=f.__name__
    return wrap
```

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='rel_from_set',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
    related_name='rel_to_set',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
    db_index=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user_from} follows {self.user_to}'
user_model = get_user_model()
user_model.add_to_class('following',
 models.ManyToManyField('self',
 through=Contact,
 related_name='followers',
 symmetrical=False))
```

could there be a problem in javascript?

Comment: Try printing some variables across your stack to see if everything is coming through as expected.